# How to Stop observable from subscribing to a queue once the required object is received?

Tags: queue, apache-camel, rx-java, observable

I am using RXJava to get element from a queue based on a selector. Once I get the first element from the queue, or the message match  a specific condition, I want to stop observing on the queue. How can I do it?

```
ReactiveCamel rx = new ReactiveCamel(camel);
Observable<Message> observable = rx.toObservable("activemq:queue:MyQueue?selector=eventType%3D'custom_message'");
```

Comment: check first() or take(1) operators

Comment: I have already tried this. But still I can see the consumer in ActiveMQ console. Once I getting the response, I want to release that connection to queue. That is where I find difficulty.

Comment: If you use `take(1)` and an item is emitted, the subscription will be disposed. If you provide an `onCompleted` method to `subscribe` and debug into it, you must see that it is called after the first emission of a message.

Comment: check takeUntil, takeWhile

Comment: When I five first() or take(1) and it receives item, control is going to onCompleted(). But the activeMQ connection is still live. As mentioned in the question, I am using reactive Camel to observe on the queue. I have tried using unsubscribe also, but no luck.`observable1.first().subscribe(new Subscriber<Message>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
     System.out.println("Completed"); 
     System.out.println("Unsubscribed? : "+this.isUnsubscribed());
     observable1.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate());
     this.unsubscribe(); 
     
     
    }`

Comment: If I check within the camel context, I can see the endpoints after the onComplete() event is triggered. Is there a way I can release the consumer from camel context?